# How should git tagging work with a multi-module Gradle project?

Tags: git, gradle, multi-module

We recently converted some projects into multi-module Gradle projects and our build pipeline is still working just fine to create built artifacts from each module, but I'm not sure how we should handle the git tags. Should the entire repository always be tagged with the same version for each module or is there a good way to tag each module separately?

An example I found (https://github.com/sonatype/sonatype-aether) seems to reflect that each module's version gets incremented together which makes sense with that the entire repository is what's been "tagged," but I'm curious if there are other reasonable options.

Comment: A tag is “global”. You could invent schemes like `module1/tagX`, `module2/tagX`, though.